# Тип лямбда-выражения

Tags: c++, c++11

При создании лямбды её тип имеет вид `lambda...`, где `...` - какое-то число. Как это число генерируется и что обозначает?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это число ничего не обозначает и нужно для того чтобы получилось какое-то уникальное имя.
Каждый компилятор генерирует эти уникальные имена по-своему, так что там может и не быть ни числа ни `lambda`.